# django query get last n records

Tags: django

Lets say I am implementing a message stream, records sort by ID ascending order, each fetch request, I want to only allow to fetch the most latest 10 records.

I tried:

```
Messages.objects.filter(since=since)[:-10]
```

And I had an error saying Negative Indexing is not supported.

My current work around is sort ID descending order, and then run:

```
Messages.objects.filter(since=since)[:10]
```

But this requires the front end to reverse the order again.

My question is, is there a elegant way to do it?

Answer (score 139, accepted):

You can pass your queryset to [reversed](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reversed):

```
last_ten = Messages.objects.filter(since=since).order_by('-id')[:10]
last_ten_in_ascending_order = reversed(last_ten)
```

Comment: Does not retrieving then indexing make it slow?

Answer (score 78):

Or use `[::-1]` instead of `reversed`:

```
last_ten = Messages.objects.filter(since=since).order_by('-id')[:10][::-1]
```

@ron_g:

> Above solution uses list comprehension twice (first to slice to 10, then to reverse). You can do it as one operation, it's 9x faster.

```
last_ten = Messages.objects.filter(since=since).order_by('-id')[:10:-1]
```

Comment: I didn't think negative indexing was supported?

Comment: It becomes a regular list, no longer a Django queryset, after the `[:10]` slicing

Comment: if your primary key is UUID this will not work because order_by('-id) would sort the ID alphabetically and UUID are always random.

Comment: +1, this helped me. However, you're solution uses list comprehension twice (first to slice to 10, then to reverse). You can do it as one operation - `last_ten = Messages.objects.filter(since=since).order_by('-id')[:10:-1]`. I timed it using a standard list and it's 9x faster.

Answer (score 34):

If you want last X records sorted in descending order by **id** , Then I don't think you need *since* filter

```
last_ten = Messages.objects.all().order_by('-id')[:10]
```

Using **-id** will sort in descending order.
Hope this was helpful !!

Comment: How efficient is this query in comparison to the accepted answer? Thanks.

Comment: filter uses `where` clause, while above query is a plain select with `order by` clause

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to retrieve the last 25 messages and solved this problem in the following way

```
#models.py

class Meta:
        ordering = ['created']
```

```
#views.py

message1 = []
    for message in pm_messages.objects.filter(room=room_name).reverse()[0:25]:
        message1.append(message)
    messagess = message1.reverse()
```

Answer (score 1):

In response to [ron_g](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4916945/ron-g)'s comment in [Omid Raha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/538284/omid-raha)'s answer:

Consider the case where there are less than 10 records in the list:

Note that this approach

```
list[:10:-1]
```

will return an empty list, in contrast to

```
list[:10][::-1]
```

which will return all the records in the list, if the total records are less than 10.

Answer (score -1):

you can convert the queryset to a list and select the last n elements normally

```
messages = list(Messages.objects.filter(since=since))
messages = oldMessageis[-n:len(oldMessageis)]
```

Comment: Converting to a list will get all the rows from the table and is not efficient.