# django query get last n records on database server

Tags: python, sql, django

Hi accroding to [django query get last n records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20555673/django-query-get-last-n-records)

Is it good idea to get this last n record using [:n]? Can I do it on database serwer (for example in sql "select top 10"), not on server where is django?

Comment: That *is* running in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think for small records in the database say for 1k records, its fine using [django query get last n records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20555673/django-query-get-last-n-records) but for huge records in the table say 1M rows, its not the best way.

Getting n records from database server itself will be efficient than getting last n records as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20555673/django-query-get-last-n-records) by django, because in this case total records are ordered then fetched and among those we are slicing last n records, if you have a choice to execute the query directly on a database server, you should go for it rather that using Django ORM as Django ORM is time and memory consuming.

> order_by('?') queries may be expensive and slow, depending on the
>   database backend you’re using.
>   [Details here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#order-by)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is fine to use.

> Internally, a QuerySet can be constructed, filtered, sliced, and
>   generally passed around without actually hitting the database. No
>   database activity actually occurs until you do something to evaluate
>   the queryset.

Read the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/) for more details.